# Error while executing SQL query on database 'WEATHER': near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

I have this task on sql where I have to select some particular rows from a table in my database based on the differences between rows in the table but I keep getting Error while executing SQL query on database 'WEATHER': near "(": syntax error.. please what am i doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    *
    ,LAG(TempHighF,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS previousTempHigh
FROM
    weatherdata
WHERE
    TempHighF - previousTempHigh >= 10;
```

Comment: I have version 3.30.0 @forpas

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the column `previousTempHigh` which is actually an aliased window function in the `WHERE` clause.
Use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(TempHighF,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS previousTempHigh
  FROM weatherdata
)  
WHERE TempHighF - previousTempHigh >= 10;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tuKqQXM47T6mmknMCWRkVV/1).